# Delete or edit postmeta with specific meta_key?

Tags: php, customization

I am trying to create a function which either deletes all the postmeta with the meta_key "bakground-video", or edits the meta_value to empty it from the values.
There might be multiple postmeta with the meta_key "background-video" and I want the function to run on all of them.

I will use this function on a multisite when a user changes role to "basic" this will fire and delete or edit all the postmetas with the key. How would I make this happen? All of the functions I can find when searching requires me to know the post_id, which I don't know.

This is what I have come up with after some searching, but I can't make it work!

```
    $args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
                   'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                   'post_type'       => 'attachment',
                   'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
                   );
    $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );

    foreach( $all_ids as $ai ) {

       update_post_meta( $ai->post->ID, 'background-video', '' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

This is inserted in a function which fires when a user changes role to a role called "basic".

EDIT: Together with user role change function:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {


            $args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
                           'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                           'post_type'       => 'attachment',
                           'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
                           );
            $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                    $all_ids->the_post();
                    update_post_meta( $p->ID, 'background-video', '' );
                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();


    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this might be what you're looking for:

```
$args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
               'posts_per_page'  => -1,
               'post_type'       => 'attachment',
               'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
               );
$all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
        $all_ids->the_post();
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'background-video', '' );
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

### References

- [`WP_Query` » Usage » Standard Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#standard-loop)

Comment: Thank you a lot Pat, but sadly I could not make it work. Check the original post, I edited it with the complete function, which should fire this when a user changes role to "basic", but nothing in the database was changed. So it doesn't work.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice you were setting `'fields' => 'ids'`. I've updated my code to reflect that. (Specifically I'm using `get_the_ID()` rather than `$p->ID` in the `update_post_meta()` call.)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, it is much appreciated! I tried your code, with the function I posted in the main post. But still nothing happens when switching user role. The postmetas with meta_key background-video still has a meta_value.

Comment: I'm afraid it's time for you to debug, then. Usually I throw in a lot (like a *lot*) of `var_dump()`s as I go, to inspect every line to see where something's going wrong. For example, `update_post_meta()` will return a boolean `true` or `false` on success or failure, so you should probably start with something like `$x = update_post_meta( {etc} ); var_dump( $x );` and see if it's `false`. At least then you'll know *where* the problem is, even if you're not sure *what* it is.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it, I think the issue was that I hade the wrong post_type. Now it works fantastically!

Thanks a lot for all the help!

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {
            $args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
                           'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                           'post_type'       => 'slide',
                           'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
                           );
            $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                    $all_ids->the_post();
                    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'background-video', '' );
                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Yeah, having the wrong `post_type` in your query will make a difference. I'm glad you got it solved.

Comment: Yes, so sorry for that mistake! And Thank you very very much!!